# Error send an email with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

How can I send an email from a form with symfony2?

*app/config/config_dev.yml:*

```
swiftmailer:
    delivery_address:  dev@example.com
```

*Controler:*

```
public function aboutAction($name) {
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('x@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('x@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($this->renderView('AgLogBundle:Mail:email.txt.twig', array('name' =>     $name)));

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->render('AgLogBundle::ajouter.html.twig');
}
```

*Error:*

> Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with
>   host 127.0.0.1 [Aucune connexion n�a pu �tre �tablie car l�ordinateur
>   cible l�a express�ment refus�e. #10061]

Comment: Configure your server to send the emails. If you use Linux the easiest way is to install `sendmail`.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a mail server installed at localhost. You can try send emails thought Gmail using this config:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host:      ~
    mailer_user:      your_gmail_username
    mailer_password:  your_gmail_password
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Comment: it stays that way  FatalErrorException: Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp\www\AgLog\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php line 115

Comment: try now, with only this parameters

Comment: You can try increasing max_execution_time in php.ini (or with ini_set) http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Une tentative de connexion a �chou� car le parti connect� n�a pas r�pondu convenablement au-del� d�une certaine dur�e ou une connexion �tablie a �chou� car l�h�te de connexion n�a pas r�pondu.
#10060]